# Elasticseach: dot in search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 documents in elasticsearch. There is a field `domain` that has `8.8.8.8` as value and other has `ip-188-165-238.eu` as value.

When I'm trying to find `8.8.8.8` it finds both of the documents.

Problem is that the dot "." is a separator in elasticsearch and I can't find any option to escape it in search query. I tried  `8\.8\.8\.8` but still the same results.

The question is if there is any way of escaping dot in ES query? Or maybe some workaournd?

Comment: I dont think you will get both the documents when searching for `8.8.8.8`. Can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: My mapping is very complex, the problem here is not in the mapping. Question is about escaping dot in the query string